# How to keep argument names of interface after compilation in Java?

Tags: java, interface, javac

I want to keep argument names of interface methods after compilation in Java.

Below is an example.

Before compiling:

```
interface IFoo {
    void hello(String what);
}
```

After compiling using `javac -g:vars IFoo.java`

```
interface IFoo {
    void hello(String str);
}
```

The argument `what` is renamed to `str`.

How can I keep the argument names?

Answer (score 4):

An argument or local variable has no name, only a number.

I believe the command line argument for adding local variable names is `-parameters` to enable access via reflection https://www.beyondjava.net/reading-java-8-method-parameter-named-reflection

It's the decompiler's job to determine/guess a variable name.  I use Fernflower which does a reasonable job.

Input

```
import java.util.stream.Stream;

interface IFoo {
    public abstract void hello(String what);

    public static void print(String... args) {
        Stream<String> stream = Stream.of(args);
        stream.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

output using Fernflower

```
//
// Source code recreated from a .class file by IntelliJ IDEA
// (powered by Fernflower decompiler)
//
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

interface IFoo {
    void hello(String what);

    static void print(String... args) {
        Stream<String> stream = Stream.of(args);
        PrintStream var10001 = System.out;
        System.out.getClass();
        stream.forEach(var10001::println);
    }
}
```

NOTE: The `System.out.getClass();` is generated by the `javac` compiler to test for a `null` value.

Answer (score 3):

You need to generate *debugging information* when compiling. 
This is what the [Javac](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) option `-g` does:

> `-g` — Generates all debugging information, including local variables.

---

If you are using Maven, you can set `<debug>true</debug>` in the [compiler plugin's configuration](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#debug).

Comment: While working like a charm for class methods and also static interface methods it does not work for non-static interface methods.